# How to prepare json in Postman for DateTimeOffset property to explore Dynamic linq?

Tags: c#, linq, postman, dynamic-linq

DB format for StartDate is datetimeoffset(7)

For Employee entity: **Sample 1**

```
{
Name : "Employee",
Filter: "StartDate = 2017-02-03 06:01:39.6848458 +00:00"
}
```

I've tried like **Sample 2**  *Filter: "StartDate = \"2017-02-03 06:01:39.6848458 +00:00\""*

Getting error as 
**Sample1 :** "Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'DateTimeOffset' and 'Int32'" 
**Sample2 :** "Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'DateTimeOffset' and 'String'"

How to prepare the valid json for DateTime filter to explore dynamic linq?

Comment: May I clarify what are you passing the json to? An API?

Comment: @junkangli he's is using PostMan. OnDoubt, why are you including 'StartDate ='? and What is Filter?

Comment: **API is : localhost:**/api/Employee :** Filter is the property which accepts any combination of filters to query the DB. Lets say, to query Employee > I can use 'n' combination of filters like "only Isactive or start/end filter or with employee display name, etc., "

Comment: @OnDoubt can you share the code of the API?